# Crystal Reports EvaluateAfter Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a value in a subreport that I want to include in the calculation of a formula in the main report.  To get this value, I'm using a Shared variable between the subreport and the main report.  The subreport is in a group footer and I placed the formula (lets call it FormulaShared) in the report footer (the section right after the group footer).

I can see the value the shared variable gets in the report footer, so I know that part is working.  The formula that is using this value though is not able to get the right value.  The evaluation time for this formula is set to EvaluateAfter(FormulaShared), so I would think that the calculation would be done after the value is printed to the report.  However, this is not happening.  So is this something that simply isn't possible to do in Crystal Reports given my report's current structure?  And if it isn't, is there any viable work-around to fix this?

I'm using Crystal Reports 10.

Comment: could you fix it? I have a similar issue